# How to create custom controls using generic.xaml in Silverlight 5 without using WPF?

Tags: silverlight

I want to create a custom controls datagrid using the generic.xaml.I have created the custom controls using the User control template in Silverlight 5. I am not using WPF.
How is it possible to create using generic.xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is called a `Templated Control` in Silverlight.

You have to provide three things:

- a class containing your control's logic
- a default `Style` with a `ControlTemplate`
- an entry in `generic.xaml` that includes the default `Style`

Example: MyFeeblefezer.cs

```
public class MyFeeblefezer : Control
{
    public MyFeeblefezer() { DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyFeeblefezer); }
}
```

and MyFeeblefezer.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Style TargetType="MyFeeblefezer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyFeeblefezer">
          <Grid>
            <!-- here goes your visible control UI parts -->
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and themes/generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyFeebleProject;Component/MyFeeblefezer.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: But Templated Control doesn't create .xaml file?

Comment: Well, create it on your own. In VisualStudio SolutionExplorer RightClick -> Add -> New Item... -> Silverlight Resource Dictionary

Comment: When I  used  DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyFeeblefezer), it gives me blank page

Comment: I'm using theclass myControl : UserControl  and  not the myControl:control with the generic.xaml. And used Templated Control only to get the generic.xaml file

Comment: You have two ways of creating custom controls: #1: derive from UserControl and have exactly one xaml file associated with it to define the visible elements. the generic.xaml is not involved. #2: derive from control (or any subtype) and provide a default style via the generic.xaml.

Comment: @Reena: You understand the different approaches? Need any clarification?

Comment: can you plz tell me which is the standard way.... usercontrol or templatedcontrol. I have used usercontrol to create custom control. But our client asked us tu use the standard way.

Comment: @Reena: The `Templated Control` approach is more flexible. You provide a default template but anybody who uses your control can overwrite the template with his own if necessary. Therefore the controls of the base class lib are templated controls. Well, I think you can say the standard way for reusable controls is the Templated approach.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. If I want the event of the DataGrid control than I can have it on the onApplyTemplate method in this way:  grid.LoadingRow += (object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) =>
            {///   code goes here }.     Am I in the Wright direction?

Comment: So finally we have created the custom control like:

1. Generic.Xaml---where the control UI behaviour is.
2. TemplateControl.cs---where events and all the logic is placed.

and we have used the dll of template control in client side. Is this the standard approach.

Comment: @Reena: Yes, that's the standard approach for custom controls. And yes, you can access your UI parts with x:Name like...var myGrid = (Grid) GetTemplateChild( "MyGridElement" ); myGrid.SizeChanged += ...